# How can I minimise what is installed by Git for Windows?

Tags: windows, git, package, package-managers

The git for Windows client appears to install an entire mingw distribution onto my machine consuming over 500MB of space.

This is nearly twice as large as the installation of Gimp for Windows!

I already have cygwin, vim and all of the other utilities I need to do my job and so have no need whatsoever for yet another copy of perl, vim, etc. I just need a git client for Windows.

How can I minimise what is being installed so that I just get a git client I can use?

Comment: You could install Git in cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are in play here:

- Whatever tool you have used to calculate the space occupied by
  the GfW install did it wrong; here's why.

  Due to historical reasons many "supplementary" Git executable files
  are now just "alternative names" for the main executable file, `git.exe`.

  To achieve this, the installer writes the `git.exe` file and then
  creates a bunch of the so-called "hard links" all pointing to that `git.exe` executable. This means a bunch of files named `git-*.exe`
  located in the `mingw32\libexec\git-core` are all mere hardlinks.

  In my (somewhat dusty) GfW install, there are 116 hardlinks to `git.exe` there.  Multiply that by circa 3 MiB and you get a value close to 350 MiB.<sup>1</sup>
- *Most* (trust me) of the bundled stuff you thnk is not related to GfW is in fact crucial for it to work, because:

  - Some bits of Git core functionality are written as shell scripts.
    A good example is `git-rebase` which has been re-written in C
    only 2 minor Git releases ago.

    Shell script implies the need to have a Windows port of a POSIX
    shell; so GfW bundles `bash`.  It also implies the need to have a set
    of utilities any Unix shell programmer expects to have available—such
    as `sed` or `awk` etc (not "just because" but because they are indeed
    used by some parts of Git code).
  - The `git svn` bridge is written in Perl and requires several Perl
    modules to be available as well as a client Subversion library.

    While not a core component, many folks take its existence
    for granted, so it's here.
  - The stock GUI utilities, `git gui` and `gitk` are written in
    Tcl/Tk,…so guess what.

    And again many folks take their availability for granted (me included).
  - The OpenSSH `SSH` client is bundled for the same reason.
  - The support for `HTTP[S]` protocol in Git is implemented using
    `libcURL` which depends on a bunch of stuff including OpenSSL.
  - Now consider that many parts of those pieces of software I enumerated
    have their own hard dependencies which need to be bundled as well.

So, we are basically left with two bundled pieces of software which are
not strictly needed: Vim and Mintty.
The opinion of the folks working on GfW is that they are expected to be
available by those who prefer to work with GfW from the Git Bash window.
Simply put, they are there for those who came from Unix land or switch
systems back and forth between Windows and Unix-like ones (Mac OS X included).

So… If you think about this a bit more, when, say, on a typical
GNU/Linux-based OS you do somehing like

```
apt install git git-gui gitk git-svn
```

you just don't give a heck about the dependencies because

- Everything just works and
- Chances are very high you already have 95% of the
  dependencies (including the transitive ones) installed anyway.

This makes the installation of Git to appear as if it has almost zero dependencies which is wrong.

Windows, on the other hand,

- Does not have a package manager.
  (And no, Chocolatey and NuGet are not them.)
- Does not have those 95% of of "the dependencies" already installed.

As you can supposedly see now, the GfW developers had no other sensible
way to go around implementing this product short of bundling all that stuff.
After all, a typical Joe Random Developer expects to download the installer, click through it and get a fully working product as the result.

The situation is going to improve on this front a bit:
since the start of the 2.x branch, GfW strives to piggyback on the Msys2
ecosystem as much as possible, and this includes its package management
facility (based on the Windows port of `pacman` IIRC).
I'm not sure whether it works *now* but the goal was to eventually make
GfW installable piecemeal by having it available as a set of Msys2 packages.
If you want a status update on this, feel free to ask on the GfW mailing list.

To recap, if not already there, there will be two ways to get GfW on your
system: via the (full) installer and via the Msys2 ecosystem and its own
package manager.  The latter facility will enable you to install only
a minimum amount of stuff (in exchange to some overhead incurred by the
package manager's bookkeeping).

---

<sup>1</sup> That won't work if you have installed GfW on a filesystem which does not support hardlinks—such as FAT32.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation - I guess the key thing is that "git" has not been architected to exist in isolation of a (nearly) fully fledged *NIX environment.

That's not readily obvious when running an install on Windows as there is little explanation of what different components it's installing.

Comment: Even more: it has been architected specifically to manage the source code of Linux, and 99.9% of the development of Linux naturally happens on Linux-based systems. ;-) The real problem though is that Windows is a pretty stripped down OS if you compare it to, say, any popular Linux-based OS such as Debian. There, when the next release is prepared, most of the work done by maintainers is that of *integration,* so you have all the available software play nicely with each other. With Windows, that's not the case: every ISV jumps through the hoops all by theirselves and ensures compatibility...

Comment: ...only with the stuff they care about.  And there's no package manager and a "blessed" repository from where you could, say, get an installation of Perl which is verified to work with the rest of the system. E.g., there are at least two popular Perl builds: Strawbery Perl and ActivePerl; they're not compatible with each other, not compatible with `git-svn` either, and anyway you can't make the GfW installer so somehow automatically fetch and install a Perl package that works with GfW.

Comment: As you can see the integration into the Msys2 ecosystem solves only one part of the equation -- packaging -- but it's unable to solve the bigger problem of Windows essentially being a "core + software from Mcrosoft" system with all the other software packages you may install not producing "the whole system" with verified interdependencies. I'm afraid this particular problem will still exist in the forceeable future.

Comment: Acknowledging your point that the official download is only 35MB - and deleting my comment that said otherwise: it's still unnecessarily large. Microsoft provide both an excellent maintained openssh for Windows https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH and bash is included in Windows 10.